# Overwritten Windows with Kali Linux - can I get back my files?

Tags: kali-linux, data-recovery

I recently installed Kali Linux on my Lenovo Ideapad that was previously running Windows 10. Now whenever I switch on my laptop all I get is a Kali Linux screen showing three options, and I can't go back to Windows.

Here is the output of `fdisk -l`:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 465.78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: ST500LM00-SSHD-
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 * 512  bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes/ 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FC7E0F6B-08DF-41AF-A78C-6117BA015BEF

Device        Start        End    Sectors    Size Type
/dev/sda1      2048    1050623    1048576    512M EFI System
/dev/sda2   1050624  968564735  967514112  461.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3 968564736  976771071    8206336    3.9G Linux swap
```

I have files I need in Windows. How can I go back to Windows?

Comment: you can reinstall windows

Comment: you should have paid attention to the comment on your previous question

Comment: For reference, [Installation error of Kali Linux on my Lenovo ideapad](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/581773/100397)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you installed Kali *over* Windows.

There is no Windows anymore, it's gone, overwritten by your install.

Including all files of course.

Comment: I can't get back my files???

Comment: What did you expect? You formated the disk and wrote a Kali system on it (I'm sure it warned multiple times before dokng it). You don't have a magical second 'shadow' disk that kept Windows for you...

Comment: but I have important files in there

Comment: @user762391 You **had** important files there.

Comment: Did you create a backup before installing Kali? That's your only chance to retrieve your files.

Answer (score 2):

As others have already said, you have unfortunately completely replaced your Windows installation with Kali. You can't go "back" to Windows because Windows is no longer installed. (You can download the ISO from Microsoft's site and install that; hopefully your PC will automatically re-register your licence for you. But don't even consider this until you've recovered as much as you can from your previous installation.)

You might be able to recover your important files using a forensics tool such as one of these:

- RecuperaBit - https://github.com/Lazza/RecuperaBit
- TestDisk - https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

You should not write on or use your Kali installation, as the longer it's running the more likely it will overwrite another party of the previous Windows installation.

Find a USB disk and use that instead

Answer (score 0):

Your files are gone. In the process of installing Kali, you formatted the disk, which deleted the partition table that held metadata about the addresses of everything stored on that disk. Now the bits on that disk simply look like unreadable garbage.

As a side note, you should probably understand how this part of the system works before delving into the use of hacking tools like Kali.